# javascript and html with brackets

Tags: javascript, html

this is most likely a no brainier, but i have Brackets as a codding environment if you will, i think it covers like 30 langues or something crazy like that, and well i understand you need sorts of compilers and what not, but here im trying to add some javascript to some html externally, and i kinda plucked some code off the internet to make sure my test code wouldn't have any issues. any ways the real question is , do i need a compiler of sorts for java, if that's stupid (because i think it can be done with notepad honestly) then please take one sec to look at my code and tell me what i might be doing wrong, because i really try to be simple with my tests

THE HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <Title>Lets Do Something</Title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="Index.css"/>
        <script src="Index.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <input type="text" name="inputbox" value=""><p>
            <input type="button" name="button" value="'Click" onclick="testresults(this.form)">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

THE JAVASCRIPT

```
function testResults (form) {
var TestVar = form.inputbox.value;
alert ("You typed: " + TestVar);
```

}

in fact, Below is the site i got it from, but changed from internal script to external scripting
https://www.javaworld.com/article/2077176/scripting-jvm-languages/using-javascript-and-forms.html

Any help would be great, thanks Bunches.

Comment: check your function name in html and javascript these must be same. And you don't need any compiler to execute javascript,any browser will do it for you. yes you can use even notepad for this. and please check whether the src path of javascript file is correct or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, this is JavaScript and not JAVA. They are not the same.

In the code you posted, there is a small error that is causing the issue.
Replace `onclick="testresults(this.form)"` with `onclick="testResults(this.form)"`.
Note that I have camel cased the `testResults` function name. This should give you the results.

```js
function testResults(form) {
  var TestVar = form.inputbox.value;
  alert("You typed: " + TestVar);

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <Title>Lets Do Something</Title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="Index.css" />
  <script src="Index.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <form>
    <input type="text" name="inputbox" value="">
    <p>
      <input type="button" name="button" value="'Click" onclick="testResults(this.form)">
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```